# How to move a circle drawn by GDI in .NET Framework with the mouse?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I drew some circles on the `Form1` using `GDI+`, and the center of the circle is a small red rectangle of  `Custom Control` which is derived from `User Control`, the `BackgroundImage` property of`Form1`'s a bitmap which is also drawn by `GDI+` with several colors.

What I want is that when I move the red rectangle(the center of circle) with a mouse, the circle will also move following the red rectangle. Using the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` event I could move the red rectangle smoothly with the mouse.

My problem is how to move the circle corresponding to the red rectangle(the center of circle).
I enabled the double buffering to solve the flicker problem. `CircleCenter` is an object of `Custom Control` class(e.g. the red rectangle). `GObject` is a Grahpics object.
Here is some key codes:

```
   public Form1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |    //enables double-buffering
                      ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                      ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
                      true);
    }

   Point CCenterPoint = new Point();
   private int Diameter = 250;
   private void CircleCenterMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
        CCenterPoint = new Point(-e.X, -e.Y);
   }

    private void CircleCenterMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
                Point MousePos = CircleCenter.MousePosition;
                MousePos.Offset(CCenterPoint.X, CCenterPoint.Y);
                CircleCenter.Location = CircleCenter.Parent.PointToClient(MousePos);
                CircleCenter.BringToFront();
                CirclePen.Color = Color.Black;
                GObject.DrawEllipse(CirclePen, CircleCenter.Left- Diameter/2, CircleCenter.Top - Diameter/2, Diameter, Diameter);
                 this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

How to remove the black circle drawn by `GDI+` produced in the `MouseMove` proceed?
I googled several websites and didn't get a satisfied answer. Hope you could give me some  hints,Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, As I understand from your question, You just need to draw a circle around the red rectangle, This is quite easy.

In the Paint event of the Form, Add the following (assuming that your red rectangle control has the name "CircleCenter" and your Form was named "Form1"):

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // get the Graphics object of the form.
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    // create a think red pen for the circle drawing
    Pen redPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 4.0f);
    // drawing the circle
    PointF ctrlCenter = GetCenterOfControl(CircleCenter);
    g.DrawEllipse(redPen,
            ctrlCenter.X - (Diameter / 2),
            ctrlCenter.Y - (Diameter / 2),
            Diameter, Diameter);
}

//The following little method to calculate the center point
PointF GetCenterOfControl(Control ctrl)
{
    return new PointF(ctrl.Left + (ctrl.Width / 2),
            ctrl.Top + (ctrl.Height / 2));
}
```

Any way, I know it looks long for such a simple task like Circle drawing! here is the ugly one line version of the above code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 4.0f), (centerCircle.Left + (centerCircle.Width / 2)) - (Diameter / 2), (centerCircle.Top + (centerCircle.Height / 2)) - (Diameter / 2), Diameter, Diameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to always reset the entire GObject (erase the images you drawn on it) and then redraw them all again.

This can be done by simply drawing a rectangle with the color of the object from which you obtained the Graphics object (although you didn't mentioned it, I think GObject is a Graphics object, obtained of some win control?).

So something like:

```
Control control = CircleCenter.Parent; // Parent control where you get Graphics object from.
System.Drawing.SolidBrush sBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(control.BackColor); // Brush to be used with the same color like the one of the parent control.
GObject.FilledRectangle(sBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height); // Erase background.
GObject.DrawEllipse(CirclePen, CircleCenter.Left- Diameter/2, CircleCenter.Top - Diameter/2, Diameter, Diameter); // Do your stuff.
```

should hide the old drawings and re-draw the circle on the new location.

Comment: I think resetting the entire GObject consumes too much resources and affects the responding time of the Form.

Comment: I asumed you will be moving the control with the mouse, in this case what is drawn in previous _Paint events will be left (since the form is not fully redrawn and you will need to take care of it. That's why you need to draw a rectangle the size of the form with the same background color first and then draw the circle on top of it.

Comment: yes, GObject is a Graphics object, obtained of the `Form1`.And I could not find `DrawFilledRectangle`.Is it mean `FillRectangle`?

Comment: Done.
Please note that you will need to take care for other drawings you want to persist as well. For example if you have two circles, by moving the first one, you will need to reset the screen and redraw BOTH as the other will disappear otherwise. You will basically need to have some way of representing what's on the canvas.

Comment: `GObject` is an image of `Form1`'s `BackgroundImage` property. I've tried your method. When I move the `CircleCenter`, the canvas mostly is white and with one red circle. What I drew before with several colors is lost including the other circles.

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in one of my previous comments "Please note that you will need to take care for other drawings you want to persist as well". You will need to do the following: 1. Clear the screen. 2. Draw all objects first except the object that's moving. 3. Draw the new object (so it will be on top of other objects in case it overlaps with any of them). So you will basically need to have a representation of the objects in the memory (I wil suggest you to create classes for them, that can be serializeable so you can easilly save them to file in case you need).